# Way to show merging status in command line in git

Tags: git, command-line, bash

I currently have git configured to show which branch I am on, (and my command line to show which directory I am on) with the following bash script:

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\] \[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\] (\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)) \$  \n$ "
export PS2="$ "
```

I am wondering if there is a way to show show the "merging" status, so that when I am merging it also says `merging` in the command line (after which branch I am on).  I have seen this elsewhere so I am pretty sure it is possible but do not know how.

Comment: You could check for the existance of a `MERGE_HEAD` file in the `.git` folder to determine if you are in a merge process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see in [this git-ps1](https://github.com/jbalogh/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/git-ps1) script a much more complete status indicator, with rebase and merge in it.

```
local g="$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)"
if [ -n "$g" ]; then
  local r
  local b
  if [ -d "$g/rebase-apply" ]
  then
    if test -f "$g/rebase-apply/rebasing"
    then
      r="|REBASE"
    elif test -f "$g/rebase-apply/applying"
    then
      r="|AM"
    else
      r="|AM/REBASE"
    fi
    b="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
  elif [ -f "$g/rebase-merge/interactive" ]
  then
    r="|REBASE-i"
    b="$(cat "$g/rebase-merge/head-name")"
  elif [ -d "$g/rebase-merge" ]
  then
    r="|REBASE-m"
    b="$(cat "$g/rebase-merge/head-name")"
  elif [ -f "$g/MERGE_HEAD" ]
  then
    r="|MERGING"
    b="$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)"
```

For the merge part, it does indeed test for `MERGE_HEAD` file, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690649/way-to-show-merging-status-in-command-line-in-git/24690720#comment38285676_24690649) by [Zeeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274224/zeeker).

Comment: How would I add this to my existing `export ps` ?

Comment: @Startec Actually, that script defines the variable '`r`', which then can be added to your `PS1` with '`$r`': https://github.com/jbalogh/dotfiles/blob/2853c3c78bb9c7ac21dc4028a44e10be6c3e8e2d/.zsh/git-ps1#L48

Comment: I am sorry, I am still a little lost with this code, and that gist.  It says `# returns text to add to bash PS1 prompt (includes branch name)` 

Is this something I would add in my `.bash_profile` 
Sorry, I am new to bash scripting.

Comment: @Startec yes, or your .bashrc, like so: https://github.com/jbalogh/dotfiles/blob/2853c3c78bb9c7ac21dc4028a44e10be6c3e8e2d/.zshrc#L33-L36

Answer (score 1):

As @Zeeker suggested, you basically can have something like:

```
PS1='$([[ -e .git/MERGE_HEAD ]] && echo "merging ")\$ '
```

Or

```
PS1="\$([[ -e .git/MERGE_HEAD ]] && echo 'merging ')\\\$ "
```

You can merge it with your current `PS1`; customize `echo merging` or use `printf` to produce ANSI codes as well.

Comment: I am sorry but how would I merge this with my `ps1` and not overwrite anything?